# Add a string inside a specific part of a string

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<script> some random script, maybe even some line breaks\ </script>
```

or even

```
<script type="random/type" src="https://even_a_source.com"> random scripts </script>
```

I would like to insert a class tag in the script part, like this:

```
<script class="addMe" type="random/type" src="https://even_a_source.com"> random scripts </script>
```

without changing the rest of the script tag.

I figured using regex would be a good start: `/<[^>]*>/` matches `<script>` and `</script>` I think but I didn't progress further unfortunately.

As mentioned in the comments, using the gem `nokogiri` might be easier to deal with this, I'm trying it right now and update this if I find the solution.

Comment: Using regex for processing html/xml is generally considered a bad idea. Use something like nokogiri instead: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at the docs right now and I see that you can modify attributes with this gem. I'll try this and keep this thread updated!

Comment: I personally think this question wouldn't be facing a close vote if it contained some actual ruby code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `nokogiri` you can manipulate it easily:

```
doc = Nokogiri.parse('<script> some random script, maybe even some line breaks\ </script>')
doc.children.first.set_attribute('type', 'random/type')
doc.children.to_s

=> "<script type=\"random/type\"> some random script, maybe even some line breaks\\ </script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy using `Nokogiri` gem.

After installing the gem here is the code that worked for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-EOHTML

<script>
    random scripts
</script>
EOHTML

script  = @doc.at_css "script"
script['class'] = 'addMe'

puts @doc.to_html
```

This outputs the following in the console:

```
<script class="addMe">
    random scripts
</script>
```

I just have to figure out a way to fit this in my code but this shouldn't be a problem.

This closes the question.